# What is the more efficient? Fuzzy search or range search?

Tags: elasticsearch, fuzzy-search

I have a fuzzy query and its equivalent range query, and both return the same search results. 
The queries are as follows:

Fuzzy Search:

```
CURL -XGET 'localhost:9200/bank/_search?pretty' -d ' 
{
    "sort": {
      "balance": "desc"
    },
    "query": {
       "fuzzy" : {
           "balance" :{ 
              "value" :  20000,
              "fuzziness" :  10000
            }
        }
    }
}'
```

Range Search

```
CURL -XGET 'localhost:9200/bank/_search?pretty' -d '
{
    "sort": {
      "balance": "desc"
    },
    "query": {
        "range" : {
            "balance" : {
                "gte" : 10000,
                "lte" : 30000
            }
        }
    }
}'
```

So my question is which one is more efficient? Which one should be preferred over the other?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The fuzzy query uses the ["Levenshtein edit distance"](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-fuzzy-query.html). It works like this:

> The fuzzy query generates all possible matching terms that are within the maximum edit distance specified in fuzziness and then checks the term dictionary to find out which of those generated terms actually exist in the index.

So what happens is that all possible variations are created and then checked if they exist. This can way more expensive then just checking for a `gte` or `lte`, although of course your exact query vs your index size matters.

But more important: does the first even do what you think it does? Fuzzy is looking at levensteihn distance, which for instance, would be only `1` if you compare for instance your `20000` to `90000`, so I would suspect that latter to be in your resultset, which you don't even want. So while I do have a small doubt as you seem to imply it works like you want to, I'd still say the fuzzy would be the least efficient as it does not produce the actual results your are looking for.